# Отображение фигур в консоли с помощью цикла do - while

Tags: java, циклы

> Здравствуйте, пожалуйста, как вывести в консоль данную фигуру с
> помощью цикла do-while:
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> У меня есть такой вариант решения, но он не верен, так как в нем много
> проверок, подскажите как можно решить эту задачу только с помощью
> цикла do-while?

```
do {
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println(symblAce);
        } else if (i > 1 && i < 4) {
            System.out.print(symblAce);
        } else if (i == 4) {
            System.out.print("\n" + symblAce);
        } else if (i > 4 && i < 7) {
            System.out.print(symblAce);
        } else if (i == 7) {
            System.out.print("\n" + symblAce);
        } else if (i > 7 && i < 9) {
            System.out.print(symblAce);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n" + symblAce);
        }
        i++;
    } while (i <= 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Скольк строк вывести
        int countLine = 5;
        //Максимальное количество символов
        int sizeMaxLine = 3;
        //Символ, который выводим
        String symbol = "$";
        //Начальная строка
        int countShowLines = 0;
        //Увеличивать или уменьшать значения
        boolean isIncrement = true;

        while (countShowLines != countLine) {

            if (isIncrement) {
                for (int i = 1; i <=sizeMaxLine; i++) {
                    String str = symbolEqualsOnNumber(symbol,i);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    countShowLines++;
                }
            } else if (!isIncrement) {
                for (int y = sizeMaxLine-1; y>0; y--){
                    String str = symbolEqualsOnNumber(symbol,y);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    countShowLines++;
                }
            }

            if (countShowLines == sizeMaxLine) {
                isIncrement = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String symbolEqualsOnNumber(String symbol,int count){
        String result="";
        while (count!=0){
            result=result+symbol;
            count--;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

У меня получился следующий алгоритм, конечно не идеальный, так как входных условий задачи мало, просто пример, того что надо вывести. Но относительно универсальный.

Comment: Я сделал с помощью while(), но переделать не сложно. И главная особенность этого алгоритма, чтобы
переменная sizeMaxLine была кратна 3, а countLine=sizeMaxLine*2-1 или придется добавлять, думаю, доп. условия, например: int countLine = 11; int sizeMaxLine = 6;